# how to email data from edit from of sharepoint calender list

Tags: javascript, edit-form, sharepoint-email

I have a sharepoint list with 3 columns. User edits the item and updates a column. CLicks on custom button present on the ribbon for send email. The email body should contain the value of 3 columns (updated one) and also outlook client should open. I tried using mailto but, i am not able to add the item data to the body.

Is there any other approcah That i can try.

Edit: Here is the code I have written in script.js file

```
var itemID = "";
var listItemInfo = '';
var targetListItem;
function mailThisPage(olist) {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListData, "sp.js");
var mailTo = encodeURIComponent(listItemInfo) + encodeURIComponent('The following item has been updated:');
window.location = "mailto:deepika-tyagi@abc.com?Subject=Item Information&body=" + mailTo;
}
function getListData() {
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CMCalendar');
var itemId = _spGetQueryParam('id');

targetListItem = myList.getItemById(itemId);
clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'OrderSummary');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('OrderSummary'));
debugger;
listItemInfo = targetListItem.get_item('OrderSummary');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: added the code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that opens the mail client to `success` method. As JavaScript client object model runs asynchronously it doesn't wait for `success` method to complete. Hence the variable whose value is assigned in the success method is empty when calling `mailto`.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('OrderSummary'));
debugger;
listItemInfo = targetListItem.get_item('OrderSummary');
var mailTo = encodeURIComponent(listItemInfo) + encodeURIComponent('The following item has been updated:');
window.location = "mailto:deepika-tyagi@abc.com?Subject=Item Information&body=" + mailTo;
}
```

Noe that I haven't tested your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can write workflow/ event receiver on item updating calendar list to send email.